# How to let the password fix the regex rule?

Tags: regex

I would like to make a regex to fix the password role " AT LEAST 6 CHARACTERS AND 1 NUMBER "

this is my code :

```
/^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z]{6,})(?=.*?[0-9]{1,}).{7,}$/
```

but it seems wrong.

2wwwwww > fix

wwwwww2 > fix

www2www > did't fix

How to rewrite the Regex role???

Comment: Why would you want to use a regexp with that? As soon as another rule such as "at least one upper and one lower case letter" comes in, the regexp gets even more unmaintainable than it already is.

Comment: Don't try to do it all in one regex. Write one line of code to check that there's a number, and another line to check that there are at least 6 letters.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with one regex code.

Comment: @ToughCoder: This is perfectly possible with a regex since generating a DFA that does this is trivial. However the regex will have a size exponentially with the number of elements and their minimum cardinality.

Comment: @CommuSoft you are saying we can put all the possibilities in one line?

Comment: Yes: You define a regex like: `n.c.c.c.c.c.c|c.n.c.c.c.c.c|c.c.n.c.c.c.c|c.c.c.n.c.c.c|c.c.c.c.n.c.c|c.c.c.c.c.n.c|c.c.c.c.c.c.n` with `c` any character, `n` any number and `.` actually `.*` (because noise between the chars and numbers is allowed as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the risk of downvoting...

Why don't you use two regular expressions: one that checks for minimum six chars:

```
/([A-Za-z].*){6,}/
```

And another regex that checks the same lines for strings with at least one number:

```
/[0-9]/
```

If you for instance use grep, you can use a pipe (`|` in bash) to check them both:

```
grep -P "([A-Za-z].*){6,}" < file | grep -P "[0-9]"
```

Theoretically it is possible to write out such condition as one regular expression but if the regex tends to blow up with the number of required items and their minimum cardinality.

---

If you really want one regex, try:

```
/[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*|
 [A-Za-z].*[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*|
 [A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*|
 [A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*|
 [A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*|
 [A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*|
 [A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[A-Za-z].*[0-9].*/
```

With no newlines (here only used to make things clear). The `.*` parts are used to allow noise between the characters as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to cram every single bit of everything into a single regex. I strongly suggest you use multiple regexes for your password validation. Validate against one that checks that there's a digit, another that checks for uppercase letters, another for lowercase letters, etc. It will be far more readable, and much easier to modify later if you change your password requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what regexp is good for this task but try:

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)
```

Comment: '(?=.*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z][0-9]*[a-zA-Z].*)(?=.*[0-9].*)'

Comment: if you try this: asdfs6d that won't give you the result.

Comment: You need additional `.*` groups between every part (because the specification does not rule out other characters, noice, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd do:

```
^(?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){6})(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}$
```

This matches string that have at least 6 alpha and 1 digit.

It could be rewritten as:

```
^(?i)(?=(?:.*[a-z]){6})(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{7,}$
```

where `(?i)` means case-insensitive.